# Why are my images not displaying in IE?

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer

It seems IE is choosing to ignore my background images :(, its getting all the styles with layout etc but not sure where I have gone wrong

This is the 
[link removed]

css example
    body {
    background:#eae3e3 url(styles/images/bg.jpg)no-repeat center 0;
    }

Comment: Help people to help you by posting the relevant CSS fragments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your CSS file that IE can't interpret.  When you attach the background image to `body`, you forgot to put a space between the last ) in your image reference and your 'no-repeat' statement.

So change this:

```
background:#eae3e3 url(styles/images/bg.jpg)no-repeat center 0;
```

To this:

```
background:#eae3e3 url(styles/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center 0;
```

I tested this in the IE debugger and it does, in fact, fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing space after `url()`:

```
background:#eae3e3 url(styles/images/bg.jpg)no-repeat center 0;
```

Make that

```
background:#eae3e3 url(styles/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center 0;
```

and it should work.

Comment: The space after the () is what was missing, thanks for your help